# Properties not displaying from listConfig/getInnerTpl to comboBox

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, combobox

I'm successfully retrieving data from the server, but in processing the response, I can't seem to access certain properties of each object. No clue what the problem is.
My combobox successfully loads and displays each item, including the title, genre, and year. I can't seem to display the other properties.
I realize that each one-word property (like `title`) is displaying, while multi-word properties (like `item_id`) are not, which is why I tried using both `itemId` and `item_id`, but no luck. Any thoughts?

***Search.js*** (search view)
I've been playing with the syntax in the getInnerTpl function - I know it looks a little strange.

```
// Search results view

Ext.define('LibApp.view.librarian.actions.Search', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.librariansearch',
id: 'librariansearch',

require: [
    'Ext.form.field.Text',
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.layout.container.Anchor',
    'Ext.form.field.ComboBox'
],

title: 'Search Results',

layout: {
    type: 'anchor'
},

defaults: {
    margin: '10px'
},

autoScroll: true,

items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combo',
        id: 'searchcombo',
        store: 'Items',
        displayField: 'title',
        anyMatch: true,
        typeAhead: true,
        typeAheadDelay: 0,
        hideLabel: true,
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        hideTrigger:true,
        anchor: '100%',
        margin: '10px',
        emptyText: 'Enter an Item Title',

        listConfig: {
            loadingText: 'Searching...',
            emptyText: 'No matching items found.',
            // Custom rendering template for each item
            getInnerTpl: function(displayField) {
                return '<span><b>{title}</b></span>' +
                    '<br>displayField: {displayField}' +   
                    '<br>itemType: {itemType} | item_type: {item_type} | itemId: {itemId} | item_id: {item_id}' +    
                    '<br>Item Type: {itemType} | Quantity Available: {quantityAvailable} | Year: {year}' +
                    '<br>Item ID: {itemId} | Genre: {genre} | Call Number: {callNumber}';
            },

            listeners: {
                // on itemclick, open window showing item details
                itemclick: function(list, record) {
                    var resWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                        x: 100,
                        renderTo: 'librariancenter',
                        title:'Item Details',
                        height: 200,
                        width: 400,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        html: '<div><h3>  ' + record.title + '</h3>' +
                             '  Item Type: ' + record.itemType + ' | Quantity Available: ' + record.quantityAvailable + '<br>' +
                             '  Genre: ' + record.genre + ' | Call Number: ' + record.callNumber + '</div>',
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                text: 'Reserve Item',
                                handler: function(button, evt){
                                    // Show reserveitem view
                                    list.up('librariancenter').getLayout().setActiveItem('reserveitem');

                                    // Autofill fields
                                    Ext.getCmp("reserveitem").getForm().findField("item_id").setValue(record.get("item_id"));
                                    Ext.getCmp("reserveitem").getForm().findField("title").setValue(record.get("title"));

                                    // Close item detail window
                                    resWin.close();
                                }
                            },

                        ],
                    });
                    resWin.show();
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10
        } // end listConfig
    },
    {
        xtype: 'component',
        style: 'margin-top:10px',
        html: 'Live search requires a minimum of 4 characters.',
        padding: '10px'
    }
]
});
```

***Screenshot of Results*** (in the console below, you can see the response)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - found the issue. My syntax in the model followed the pattern `multiple_word` rather than standard camelCase, causing a mismatch. Changing the fields in the model solved the problem.